# OR element wise operation over two binary lists

Tags: python, list, elementwise-operations

I have the following code of two binary lists and I want to obtain a resulting list in which the element `i` will be the `OR` operation applied to the `i` elements of the two lists:

```
from operator import ior  

l_0 = [01100]
l_1 = [11000]

print map(ior, l_0, l_1)
```

And I was expecting a result of `[11100]`, but the result is:

```
[11000]
```

I have checked ior operator and the documentation says that it performs the operation:

```
a = ior(a, b) is equivalent to a |= b
```

So I tried the following to check as well:

```
print ior(0,0)
print ior(1,0)
print ior(0,1)
print ior(1,1)
```

Getting as results:

```
0
1
1
1
```

Which makes sense, but doesn't coincide with the result obtained in the 3rd position of the lists. I don't understand why the result of the map operation of above is not `[11100]`. I am missing something here and I hope that you can throw some light on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[11000]` (for example) is *not* a list of five binary digits, it's a list of one *decimal* number, `11000`.

Similarly, `01100` is a single octal number equal to `576` decimal, so:

```
11000d        = 0010101011111000b
01100o = 576d = 0000001001000000b
                -----------------
  perform or:   0010101011111000b = 11000d
```

That's why you're getting `11000` as the answer, exactly the same as if you'd done:

```
[l_0[i] | l_1[i] for i in range(len(l_0))]
```

If you want to process a list of five binary digits, that would be something like:

```
>>> l_0 = [0,1,1,0,0]
>>> l_1 = [1,1,0,0,0]
>>> [l_0[i] | l_1[i] for i in range(len(l_0))]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`01100` is octal representation (576 in decimal). `11000` is decimal representation. They are not binary representations.

To represent binary, prefix them with `0b`:

```
[`01100`, `11000`]
```

And to get binary representation from the number use `bin`:

```
bin(num)
```

or

```
'{:b}'.format(num)
```